# Prolog - subtract each item only once

Tags: list, prolog, duplicates, subtraction

when I use prolog's built-in predicate "subtract/3" : subtract(+Set, +Delete, -Result) in for example:

```
subtract([a,b,c,d,c,c,d,e], [c,a], X).  
X = [b, d, d, e].
```

but I want to subtract each item in +Delete from +Set ONCE. I mean, I want

```
subtract([a,b,c,d,c,c,d,e], [c,a], X). to give
X = [b, d, c, c, d, e].
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can build your own procedure that does that.
For example:

```
subtract_once(List, [], List).
subtract_once(List, [Item|Delete], Result):-
  (select(Item, List, NList)->
    subtract_once(NList, Delete, Result);
    (List\=[],subtract_once(List, Delete, Result))).
```

In every iteration you take one item from the list of items to remove, and extract one element from the input list, and then continue using the remainder of both lists.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your help. But there is a problem with this predicate. When I do     ?- subtract_once([a,a,b],[a,a,a],X) , it gives X=[b]. But I want it to give false in this situation. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 2):

You can do something along these lines :

```
subtract_custom(Remainder, [], Remainder).
subtract_custom(List, [Current|Delete], X) :-
    select(Current, List, Rest),
    subtract_custom(Rest, Delete, X).
```

It's if you want it to fail when a deletion fails. Else you got to adapt it a little.

Comment: thanks for your effort, but gusbro had already gave the answer.  Is there a way to "reward" both of the answerers?